# Tensorflow in R: file name conversion issue

Tags: r, tensorflow, installation

I have the following issue while installing tensorflow on R (already installed it for python on the same machine, and it works):

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")

...

library(tensorflow)

install_tensorflow()

>>Error in dir.exists(x) : file name conversion problem -- name too long?
```

(OS:Win 7 64 bit)

Comment: You should probably include OS information.

Comment: The error clearly states that this is a file name problem, you should also attach the name of the default installation directory. You can also refer to this one in one of the top google search results: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200658453-Error-in-file-exists-outfile-file-name-conversion-problem-name-too-long-